# Import HTML/XML Google Sheets from subpage

Tags: html, import, google-sheets

Im trying to import data from a website into my Google Sheet form using both `IMPORTHTML` and `IMPORTXML`.

The target page is https://ams.gru.com.br/departure.html, however both functions keep getting the data from the initial page https://ams.gru.com.br, as if they ignore the "**/**" after the adress.

So for example, when I try `=IMPORTXML("https://ams.gru.com.br/departure.html";"//div")`it brings the `div`from the initial page (https://ams.gru.com.br) instead from the subpage (https://ams.gru.com.br/departure.html).

Any ideas on how do I get the data from the subpage?

Comment: I get a 404 error for your link. Note that Google's import functions don't work for dynamically generated content

Comment: Sorry, there was missing the ".html" at the end of the adress, but even with it the link does not go straight to the "departure" subpage, it stays on the initial page.
To get to the target page is necessary to click on the option below "todos" (which means All) to see all flights.

So if the data is updated automatically the function will not work?
I would like to get the gate position of the flights as they are updated, is it possible?

Comment: I get redirected from the page you input, back to the main page, because you are attempting to access something that is behind a log-in screen. Google's robots that do the work have anonymous access, so they, too, cannot get to the page you want. If you want flight data, you will need to use whichever API the webpage you reference uses (or whatever public API the company provides). That will likely require you to write code. It's also entirely possible the company does not allow public access to that API. I suggest contacting them.

Comment: I see, makes sense. I'll try to contact them and see if they can help me on that, thank you very much for the clarification!
Can you tell me how do I mark your comment as "solved my question"?